# TypeError: window.gtag is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, google-tag-manager

I'm totally puzzled with GTM, I implemented it to my webSite to trigger some events to handle traffic, ect... It's be like 2 days I saw the following error :

```
Error from the trackerPageView =>  TypeError: window.gtag is not a function
    at _app.js:1
    at _app.js:1
    at commons.c57c1be722ad069a7405.js:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (commons.c57c1be722ad069a7405.js:1)
    at commons.c57c1be722ad069a7405.js:1
```

I didn't see any doc about this problem so I make a post to centralize information about this problem.

My config is a webApp (nextjs, Reactjs, typeScript, redux), hopefully this will help.

_document.tsx :

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { GA_TRACKING_ID } from "../lib/gtag";
import { Fragment } from "react";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  setGoogleTags() {
    return {
      __html: `
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${GA_TRACKING_ID}');
          `,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="fr">
        <Head>
          <Fragment>
            <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.setGoogleTags()} />
          </Fragment>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            href="***"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="***.css"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <noscript>
            <iframe
              src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
              height="0"
              width="0"
              style={{ display: "none", visibility: "hidden" }}
            ></iframe>
          </noscript>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <script
            type="text/javascript"
            id="hs-script-loader"
            async
            defer
            src="//js.hs-scripts.com/*****.js"
          ></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

gtg/index.ts:

```
export const GA_TRACKING_ID = 'GTM-XXXX'

export default function trackPageView(url) {
    try {
      if (window.gtag)
        window.gtag("config", GA_TRACKING_ID, {
        page_location: url,
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error from the trackerPageView => ", error);
  }
}
```

> Solution I found temporary!

So currently my implementation of gtag let me to have firer and trigger detected by GTM, I just set a new trigger to

> History modification

and now it's firing my events assigned with this trigger at each history modification. I'm not very confortable with gtag but this enough for me (for now), I'm still annoyed because of the implementation I did. I would like to find the right implementation to clean mine.

The problem clearly come from the SSR because the window variable is become undefined (don't exist in nodeJs) to the error above appear. Still search solution to fix it...

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14980

Thx everyone and have a good day :)

Comment: You'll either want to make sure that the google tag manager's script is loaded before your app bundle, or initialize it yourself in trackerPageView when it's used for the first time. And add a try-catch inside trackerPageView because if a user uses an ad blocker, the script will be blocked and window.gtag will not be initialized.

Comment: I all ready add a try-catch where I call it that's why I do not crash but got the pretty error message... Ok but how can I check if the google tag manager is loaded before my app bundle ? (I can publish more code if it's can help)

Comment: Make sure the <script> is before your <script>. And `if (window.gtag) { }`

Comment: where did you execute `window.gtag`, and where did you define `function gtag()`? You can reference this [article](https://hoangtrinhj.com/using-google-analytics-with-next-js) to set up the google analytics.

Comment: Nextjs + GTM... Thats the problem, they can work, but you'll need to ensure it doesnt fire during a server render... thus odds are your next app is using SSR... & window is not available on the server... try wrap your GTM code in a check for window. eg `if (window) {}`

Comment: I just updated the post

Comment: Ok but that's what I did no? what you think  ?

Comment: `window.gtag` will still break during ssr because window is undefined.

Comment: Ok so how should I fix the window undefined problem ? have you some suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to check for the existence of the window before using `window`.

For example:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.gtag("config", GA_TRACKING_ID, {
    page_location: url,
  });
}
```

Also you do not need to wrap your Google Tag Manager script in `<Fragment>`

Lastly, it looks like `gtag` is not something globally available by default. You have to set it up yourself according to this document: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs

Comment: In accord with @james and @h13o, `npm install @types/gtag.js` should be included in this answer

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, i used a slightly different version than the other suggestions:

```
if (typeof window.gtag !== 'undefined')
```

Comment: This was the necessary addition for Next Js applications

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I forgot to add `@types/gtag.js`.

For example,

```
npm install @types/gtag.js --save-dev
```

Comment: Types don't effect the existence or not of a global object

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was I used `import Script from "next/script";` instead simple html `script`. Hope it 'll help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't define the `gtag` in `_document.tsx`, try to add the script in `<Head>`. Also, add the script which link to `gtm`.

```
<Head>
  <script
     async
     src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
  />
  <script
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: `
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());

                gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
                  page_path: window.location.pathname,
                });
        `,
     }}
  />
</Head>
```

Comment: You should add the script which link to the `gtm`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented following this article and it works perfectly!
https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/22/reactjs-using-google-analytics-tag-manager

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    dataLayer: Record<string, any>[];
  }
}

 React.useEffect(() => {
    const analytics = (
      w: Window,
      d: Document,
      s: string,
      l: string,
      i: string
    ) => {
      (w as any).dataLayer = (window as any).dataLayer || [];
      (w as any).dataLayer.push({
        "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(),
        event: "gtm.js",
      });
      var dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
      var scr = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
      /*
        To avoid Multiple installations of google tag manager detected warning
    */
      if (!scriptExists(scr)) {
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j: HTMLScriptElement = d.createElement("script");
        j.async = true;
        j.src = scr;
        f?.parentNode?.insertBefore(j, f);
      }
    };
    const scriptExists = (url: string) => {
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
      for (var i = scripts.length; i--; ) {
        if (scripts[i].src == url) return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
    analytics(
      window,
      document,
      "script",
      "dataLayer",
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development" ? `${gaTrackingId}` : "GTM-XXXXXX"
    );
  }, [gaTrackingId]);
```